# I want to disable the dot(.) from showing on input display

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, numbers

So I have a code component which handles Five different input fields, Two of them are Floats which works perfect but other Three are Integer only I can't find a way to make (.)Dot from showing up in the integer field when I type.

```
<input
type="number" 
name={name} 
value={value} 
onChange={handleChange}/>

const handleChange = (e) => {   
      const { parseType } = props; // This passes either 'int' or 'float'

      if (validateFloatInt(e.target.value, parseType)) {
        props.updateProjectProperties(e.target.name, 
        e.target.value.replace(/^0+/, '') || 0); 

        //This is to remove the default 0 value from the start and Irrelevant and I convert it from String to Number in next component
//The e.target.value which is sent to updateProjectProperties is the value which goes to input's value
    }   
};

const validateFloatInt = (value, type) => {
    if ((type === 'float' && (value % 1 !== 0) && (value.length <= 9)) || (type === 'float' && (value % 1 === 0) && (value.length <= 6))) {
      return true;
    } if ((type === 'int' && value.length <= 6 && (value % 1 === 0))) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };
```

So Float Box works perfectly.
But in Integer Box when I type '55.' the dot(.) is displayed, I want to hide the dot(.) when the props.parseType === 'int'

Comment: if validateFloatInt return false then you didn't handle the else part, you need to prevent update or change value by using e.target.value = e.target.value.slice(0, -1)

Answer (score 0):

You can allow or prevent some key presses for input form.
With this code you can allow only number row buttons, numpad number buttons and some navigation buttons.

```
$(document).on("keydown", ".my-int-input-field", function (e) {
        if ((e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) //numbers
            && e.keyCode !== 96 //keypad numbers
            && e.keyCode !== 97
            && e.keyCode !== 98
            && e.keyCode !== 99
            && e.keyCode !== 100
            && e.keyCode !== 101
            && e.keyCode !== 102
            && e.keyCode !== 103
            && e.keyCode !== 104
            && e.keyCode !== 105
            && e.keyCode !== 8 //backspace
            && e.keyCode !== 13 // ender
            && e.keyCode !== 9 //tab
            && e.keyCode !== 37 // left arrow
            && e.keyCode !== 39 //right arrow
            && e.keyCode !== 46 //delete
                ) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Note. May be it would be more easy for you to set input as type="number" and prevent from pressing dot and comma (remember there is also comma in numpad) also you would like probably set step="1" in that case.
Here table of some keycodes https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: Input type number totally ignored the dot(.) so I cant perform any action on it.

Comment: You can enter "5.(dot)" and console log e.target.value and it will not output .(dot)

Answer (score 0):

This way can't prevent copy and paste.

```js
function numberOnly(event) {

 switch (event.target.dataset.mytype) {
 case 'int':
  if (['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'].includes(event.key)) {
   return true;
  } else {
   return false;
  }
  break;
 case 'float':
      console.log(event.target.value);
  if (event.key === '.') {
   if(event.target.value.includes('.')){
    return false;
   }else{
    return true;
   }   
  }
  else {
   if (['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'].includes(event.key)) {
    return true;
   } else {
    return false;
   }
  }
  break;
 default:
  break;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
Enter your int: <input type="text" data-mytype="int" onkeypress="return numberOnly(event)"/>
<br>
Enter your float: <input type="text" data-mytype="float" onkeypress="return numberOnly(event)"/>
</body>
</html>
```